# Discord.py default value if not given

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def move(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    await member.edit(voice_channel=channel)
```

I am trying to make that **if *channel* is not set then make it 687744572042117243** any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1. You set it to None and check in the command.
2. Set channel directly in the arguments

1st Way:

```py
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    channel = channel if channel else bot.get_channel(687744572042117243)
    await member.edit(voice_channel=channel)
```

2nd Way:

```py
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=bot.get_channel(687744572042117243)):
    await member.edit(voice_channel=channel)
```